# Limiting total web script accesses per second: good idea or not? how to implement?

Tags: php

I am wondering how one would limit accesses per second globally - for all IPs, not per IP - to prevent password cracking by a botnet or similar.  This would effectively turn a password cracking attack into a DDOS attack.

Note that expected traffic to this script is very low (1 access per day).

For example

```
//pseudocode...
while (now() - last_access < 1 second)
    sleep(0.3 seconds)

last_access = now()
```

Two questions

1. is this a good idea?
2. how to do it in PHP?  (as I don't have control over apache config)

**Edit:**  If n users are trying to access the site at once, I am happy for each one to wait n seconds.  They only need to load one page each.

Comment: The site has only one access per day??

Comment: It's actually a license server.  Ok, it could have considerably more than that at peak loads, but 1/day would be about average.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first, you'll need to figure out your threshold. What would count as a higher load, and what would count as a DDOS attack?

Second, you'll need to save the last_access variable somewhere more permanent, like a database.

But yes, what you're looking for is possible, and is recommended if your site is under frequent attacks.

Instead of sleep (which is useless in the case of an attack), simply show a generic

```
<h1>The server is currently experiencing extreme load. Please try again later</h1>
```

Your threshold should be something more like 5 users in the last couple of seconds (In which case you need to log all accesses over the last few seconds, and do the math yourself.

---

A better approach is to enforce user registration, and use Captchas when registering.

Answer (score 2):

If you're absolutely sure that this site is only visited once a day legitimately, you can do so, of course.

You could use PHP to write to a txt-file and store the last access there - that is, if you don't have access to a database or some other means of storing that information.

As you mentioned yourself, this could lead to your site being permanently down as even a very small attack (3-4 hits per second can hardly be called a DOS-attack) would suffice to lock you out.

Comment: Hmm.  Good point.  I think if there are 3-4 hits per second that should only last for a few seconds.  For a total of say 50 hits.  Then (if I understand my own code correctly) each client will have to wait between 0 and 50 seconds, on average 25 seconds.  Do you agree?

Answer (score 1):

There are better ways to prevent bots. First, forcing users to not be able to use your site quickly isn't a very good idea. Instead, using the same sort-of approach, you can test to see how long it's been since an IP tried to log-in. If it's, for example, under 1 second, don't even process the input and just output "Slow down!". A better way is to use a captha-similar method, like a simple math problem.

Comment: Simple math problems do not work on the slightly higher quality bots. You'll need to use a full-fledged captcha, which is downright annoying if you need it to access every page on your site.

Comment: Well, he did say that it had about 1 access per day, so he might not need a complicated system.

Comment: It's not single IPs I'm worried about - I already check they haven't accessed it too recently.  The threat is a distributed attack - multiple IPs.

Comment: If n users are trying to access the site at once, I am happy for each one to wait n seconds.  They only need to load one page each.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it.

This is basically a "How-to-DDoS-Myself" explanation.

If you set a limit and prevent access from that point on, you are simply crashing your own site - which is an end-goal of a DDoS attack anyway. Also, setting such an artificial limit will crash your site even faster than any DDoS would (as the script will need to activate before the real "hard limit" is reached).

DDoS mitigation deals with a question: "How to stay operational during a DDoS attack?" and shutting yourself down is not an answer.

It's like curing headache with cyanide - it will "technically" work, but I wouldn`t call it a cure.

Comment: I'm not trying to mitigate a DDoS, I'm not trying to defend against that.  I'm trying to defend against brute force username/password cracking, and I'm happy to turn such an attempt into a DDoS, because the consequences of the latter are not so serious.

Comment: Ok, I was addressing the DDoS aspect of this question, as I think (it this scenario) it's a more serious issue that will be harder to resolve. Just for brute force password attack I would suggest using CAPTCHAs or maybe just limiting the number of attempts or doing a Combo of both (5 attempts >> CAPTCHA).